# AWS - lambda:UpdateAlias for specific aliases

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-iam

Is it possible set a permission policy in AWS that allows one to only update a specific alias in a lambda function? (specifically, the lambda:UpdateAlias role)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a custom IAM policy, create an IAM role and apply this policy to it and then set this policy as the execution role of your Lambda.
The policy you create can include only

> "Action": "lambda:UpdateAlias",

Try following these two guides: [Creating a Role to Delegate Permissions to an AWS Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html) and [Step 2.3: Create a Lambda Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-userapp-walkthrough-custom-events-upload.html). In the second one they use the CLI but you can achieve the same in Lambda console.

To only allow access to a specific Lambda use the Resource section of the IAM policy as described [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html)

```html
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "lambda:UpdateAlias",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name"
  }
}
```

Comment: What I meant, though, is what if I want one role that can only update alias A and not the other aliases?

Comment: Then the **Resources** section is probably where you want to specify the ARN of the Lambda you want to allow UpdateAlias for. Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_resource.html)

Comment: I see you can do that; but can you be specific enough as to only allow updates for a specific alias? If I just follow what you suggested, the IAM policy allows the user to update _any_ alias.